# How to get an element the same height as browser resolution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying use jquery to set the height of an element to equal the users browser.  Here is the code I got so far that's not working. Is it because I have a minimal height set in css? I really need that class to equal the users resolution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() { 
    jQuery(".bg").css("height", jQuery(window).css("height"));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show your css as well ? better yet, can you post this on a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: http://bit.ly/Wn0FqV I added min-height of 1500px but I want it to equal the browsers instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a variable to `window.innerHeight`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    $(".bg").css("height", height);
});
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.innerHeight for more details on `window.innerHeight`.

`window.innerHeight` returns the height of the user's viewport, not *really* the screen resolution, as you were asking, but it works. There is also `window.innerWidth` and other methods of grabbing the user's screen statistics.

You can also use `self.innerHeight`, `parent.innerHeight`, and `top.innerHeight` but these have different purposes. (See link).

Also, you're using `$(window).css("height");` The jQuery `css()` function *assigns* css values, it doesn't return a string. It would be `$(window).height()` because `height()` does return a string.

```
var height = function() { return this.length; }
// height() returns "this.length"
```

Comment: You can also use (obviously) math operators to define "margin" and "padding" effects.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it keeps the image's aspect ratio

```
$(function(){
var ratio = $("img").width() / $("img").height();
var newWidth = ($(window).height()-10) * ratio;
if(newWidth > $(window).width())
        $("img").css("width","100%");
    else
        $("img").css("width",newWidth+"px");
$(window).resize(function(){
    var ratio = $("img").width() / $("img").height();
    var newWidth = $(window).height() * ratio;
    if(newWidth > $(window).width()){
        $("img").css("width","100%");

        }
    else{
        $("img").css("width",newWidth+"px");

        }
});
});
```

Comment: bit.ly/Wn0FqV I added min-height of 1500px but I want it to equal the browsers instead

Comment: All browsers automatically adjusts height if given none. So mention the width, height will be adjusted automatically to browser's height

Comment: @nagibr No, not necessarily. 1) It depends on the scenario, (the elements other values) and 2) It will automatically adjust the height of the object according to the _content_, not the window.

Comment: oh yes. am sorry, i was under the assumption that image is the only element being displayed in above context.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `jQuery(window).height()`. Windows doesn't actually have a dynamic height css property that change with resolution.

Comment: can you rewrite that I don't understand?

Comment: tried that didn't work:  $('.bg').css('height', $(window).height);

Comment: `jQuery(window).css('height')` isn't correct. Replace it with the code I've just posted.

Comment: bit.ly/Wn0FqV I added min-height of 1500px but I want it to equal the browsers instead

Comment: @Orlando: If it's just that you can use `min-height: 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

To set 'element' height the height of the window you need to.

```
$('element').height($(window).height());
```

Comment: bit.ly/Wn0FqV I added min-height of 1500px but I want it to equal the browsers instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use this javascript script to get the height and width of the browser. It supports multiple browsers as well:

```
var viewportwidth;
var viewportheight;
// the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight

if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
    viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
    viewportheight = window.innerHeight
}

// IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)

else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined' && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth != 'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
    viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
}

// older versions of IE

else {
    viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
    viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
}
```

The width and height of the browsers will be stored in the `viewportwidth` and `viewportheight` variables, respectively. You can then use something like

```
var bg = document.getElementById("bg");
bg.style.height = viewportheight;
```

This will set the element with id `bg`'s height to the view port height.

Comment: bit.ly/Wn0FqV I added min-height of 1500px but I want it to equal the browsers instead without min-height