# Multiple fullscreen divs on top of each other

Tags: jquery, css, anchor, fullscreen

I've created a site with two fullscreen divs stacked ontop of eachother. When clicking the first div I've used an anchor-link and jQuery to create a smooth scrolldown to the second fullscreen div.

Both the divs have these css attributes:

```
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;

display: -webkit-box;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;
```

These are incapsulated by a container div with these css attributes:

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

The body has overflow: hidden; and the logo-div doesn't have any css attributes at all.

Everything works great, but a problem appears when I'm down at the second div and resize the height of the browser window. The fullscreen mode of the second div then goes astray, and the first div becomes visible.

You can view the site here:
http://www.nolovelost.nu/test

Any tips on how to fix this would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Cannot replicate the issue. Can you tell which browser you have issues with?

Comment: this answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609878/set-height-for-element-by-browser-without-cutting-off-the-content/14609958#14609958

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its  working as it should !

Both divs have 100% height , when you increase the window size by **x** pixels both top and bottom div's get  **x** more pixels in height... and 'pushes' the lower div down !

im not a jquery expert... but something like this for when your on the bottom div should do the trick !

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() },  0);
                  return false;
             });
```

Comment: This seems to be working, but seeing as I actually know no jquery whatsoever, how do I make this script execute only when I'm on the lower div?

Answer (score 0):

Andsoa's answer sounds right. I was thinking of something on window.resize.

My answer isn't direct, but there are many existing scripts that accomplish what you're trying to do, so you may save some time by checking them out:
http://www.impressivewebs.com/parallax-scrolling-scripts-plugins/